# Creating Hive schema for frequently changing metadata structure for SAS table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hdfs

I have a SAS master dataset which gets appended every month and have corresponding columns added for those values. Such like below columns

Name Address Column_201809 Column_201810 Column_201811

Can you please suggest how i should handle this schema changes when writing this data back to Hadoop.

Comment: Do you have to keep adding extra columns? This would be much easier to deal with if you had `yyyymm` as an extra column and appended new rows to your table instead.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot do that as my master data should have unique rows only and inserting rows for each month would duplicate the data.

Comment: In that case you would just need to change the constraint so that each combination of date + id is unique.

Comment: That could be one of the cases.what I am looking for is something as Schema evolution so as to incorporate such changes at schema level on Hadoop side efficiently.

Comment: That is simply a difficult, *denormalized*, table design.  You are placing *date`i nformation in the table schema itself instead of in rows.  The *date* columns seem to be detail information and might not be considered *master* level records.  Is it possible you are looking for a slowly changing dimension (SCD) solution ?

Comment: @Richard that's one of the solution. But i would still like to know how to handle schema changes in hadoop